# add spinning effect to image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this floating circle with a logo. Is there a way to make it sway left and right as a 3d image? I have added a minimalistic reproducible example showing what I have at the moment. If anything is unclear, feel free to ask questions.

I want it to go sway to the left, then to the right and make it 3d. I am not sure how to transform this into a 3d image or add the effect. Can anyone help me?

I know understand that you have to use an SVG if I want this effect to occur. Here is an example of the effect. Look at the icons on the landing page of this website [matruecannabis.com/en](http://matruecannabis.com/en)

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ffc60b;
}

@-webkit-keyframes float {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0 25px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-20px);
            transform: translatey(-20px);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes float {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0 25px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-20px);
            transform: translatey(-20px);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.avatar {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px white solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
          transform: translatey(0px);
  -webkit-animation: float 3s ease-in-out infinite;
          animation: float 3s ease-in-out infinite;
}
.avatar img {
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Floating Logo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class="container">
    <a href="https://google.com">
        <div class="avatar">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/2Y8J8TC/logo.png" alt="Skytsunami"/>
        </div>
    </a>

</div>
<!-- partial -->
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want it to go up and down at the same time?

Comment: I didn't get you , what exactly do you mean by saying to make it 3d , do you want the image to rotate or what ? Because if you just want to make it go left to right you should just change the translatey to translatex.

Comment: Yes, it should keep the bouncing effect. It's a bit hard to explain but the whole circle should sway left and right horizontally. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok ! So you want the image to move from left to the right of the screen with that bouncing effect. Did I got you.

Comment: If you want an example, have a look on the landing page of this website. The icons sway left to right slightly while bouncing. https://matruecannabis.com/en/

Comment: Does that clear things up? @Tusharsaxena

Comment: Yeah it cleared it all ! I think they are using svg right there.

Comment: What does that mean? Does the SVG have an animation itself?

Comment: Sorry I don't think I am the right person to explain it to you. But yeah this is sure that they are using SVG and you can also use the same for your code. you can reference this link https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_intro.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this anything like what you're after?

Just animating `transform: translateX` on the `<a>` tag:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ffc60b;
}

@keyframes float {
  0%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0 25px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
}

@keyframes horizontal {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-20px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(20px);
  }
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

a {
  animation: horizontal 10s cubic-bezier(.81,.14,.57,.73) infinite;
}

.avatar {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px white solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  animation: float 3s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.avatar img {
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <a href="https://google.com">
    <div class="avatar">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/2Y8J8TC/logo.png" alt="Skytsunami" />
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

---

Or maybe a bit faster?

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ffc60b;
}

@keyframes float {
  0%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0 25px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
}

@keyframes horizontal {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-10px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(10px);
  }
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translateZ(0)
}

a {
  animation: horizontal 3s cubic-bezier(.3, .5, .7, 1.73) infinite;
}

.avatar {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px white solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  animation: float 3s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.avatar img {
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <a href="https://google.com">
    <div class="avatar">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/2Y8J8TC/logo.png" alt="Skytsunami" />
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

---

With 3d turning:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ffc60b;
}

@keyframes float {
  0%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 6px 7px 10px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    transform: translateY(0) skew(-2deg) rotateY(15deg);
    background-color: rgb(255, 198, 41);
    filter: brightness(0.9);
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: -10px 25px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transform: translateY(-20px) skew(2deg) rotateY(-20deg);
    background-color: rgb(245, 190, 41);
    filter: brightness(1.1);
  }
}

@keyframes horizontal {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-10px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(10px);
  }
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  // Hardware acceleration
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

a {
  animation: horizontal 3s cubic-bezier(.3, .5, .7, 1.73) infinite;
}

.avatar {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px white solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  transform-origin: top;
  animation: float 3s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.avatar img {
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <a href="https://google.com">
    <div class="avatar">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/2Y8J8TC/logo.png" alt="Skytsunami" />
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is really close, instead of it just moving left to right, it should TURN right and left, as a 3d image. Please have a look at this link, look at the icons on the landing page matruecannabis.com/en

Comment: Oh okay, added one with turning

Answer (score 0):

Here's quick way to do it.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ffc60b;
}

@-webkit-keyframes float {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0 25px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-20px);
            transform: translatey(-20px);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes float {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0 25px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-20px);
            transform: translatey(-20px);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.avatar {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px white solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  
}

.rotate {
  animation: rotation 8s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Floating Logo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class="container">
    <a href="https://google.com">
        <div class="avatar">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/2Y8J8TC/logo.png" class="rotate" width="100" height="100" />
        </div>
    </a>

</div>
<!-- partial -->
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How does making the image spin solve the OPs issue?

Comment: Thank you for your input. This isnt really what I meant. Firstly, the whole circle should be rotating. And secondly, I want it sway horizontally from left to right. @JeetPatel

Comment: I didn't modify margin padding for now to make rotating image into center of circle but I gusse you can do it your self.

Comment: He actually wants the whole thing to be 3D first and then it should look like levitating in the air.

Answer (score -2):

### To make 3d image, you can make a gif-image

The easiest for coding is to make a insert gif-image instead of the logo/icon.
The gif-file is an animated images itself and no need to code anything.

It might be a bit of work for whoever has to make the gif(animated images), but it's easy if you know how.
There are plenty of resources on how to make a gif and also tools to make a gif online as well.

HTML example (simply added the src-path to gif-image online):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Click image and say hi to google</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="https://google.com">
            <div class="avatar">
                <!--<img src="<replace image.gif location/path here to test>" alt="test.gif"/>-->
                <img src="https://media4.giphy.com/media/OhkMiKX0uMmLC/giphy.webp?cid=ecf05e47ben5f39yax86yjdknevq6lklvbb7x4gcnz9zdo89&rid=giphy.webp" alt="image.gif (Graphics Interchange Format)"/>

            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```